# Trying to apply styling to the parent div of an element linked to using :target in pure html/css

Tags: html, css

I have a document with internal links to subheaders throughout.

these subheaders belong to different categories.

I'd like to hide all category content not related to the particular #target.

```html
<html>
<style>
  .tab-folder > .tab-content {
      display: none;
  }
  .tab-folder > .tab-content:target,
  .tab-folder > .tab-content > div:target{
      display: block;
  }
</style>

<div class="tab-folder">
  <a href="#first">Show the first div</a><br>
  <a href="#second">Show the second div</a><br>
  <a href="#third">Show the third div</a><br>
  <a href="#sub-first"> show dummy in first</a><br>
  <a href="#sub-third"> show dummy in third</a><br>

  <div class="tab-content" id="first">First body! <div id="sub-first">dummy</div></div>
  <div class="tab-content" id="second">Second body!</div>
  <div class="tab-content" id="third">Third body!<div id="sub-third">dummy3</div></div>
</div>
</html>
```

ie when linking to `sub-first` I'd like all of the `first` tab-content to return to visibility.

Comment: You can't hide the parent of a div and expect a child to be visible. You need to either put each div on the same level or wrap the contents of the parent div into a wrapper that you selectively hide. I would think the former is the most sane.

Comment: Have you tried: `.tab-folder > .tab-content:not(div:target) {  display: none; }`?

Comment: @Dominik > You can't hide the parent of a div and expect a child to be visible.

That's the opposite of what I'm trying to do.

I have been linking to DivA, revealing it via target and hiding DivB, and vice versa.

While in the #DivB URL, I'd like to be able to link to a subsection of DivA, say #DivA2, and have it reveal all of A and hide B again.

Answer (score 1):

you can play with visibility and font-size instead of display:

```css
.tab-folder>.tab-content {
  visibility: hidden;
  font-size:0;
}

.tab-folder > .tab-content:target,
.tab-folder > .tab-content > div:target {
  visibility: visible;
  font-size:initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-folder">
  <a href="#first">Show the first div</a><br>
  <a href="#second">Show the second div</a><br>
  <a href="#third">Show the third div</a><br>
  <a href="#sub-first"> show dummy in first</a><br>
  <a href="#sub-third"> show dummy in third</a><br>

  <div class="tab-content" id="first">First body!
    <div id="sub-first">dummy</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-content" id="second">Second body!</div>
  <div class="tab-content" id="third">Third body!
    <div id="sub-third">dummy3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is an improvement over what I have above.
The goal is to reveal all of #first div when linking to it subdiv #dummy.